# Get logs of running process on other system

Tags: node.js, generics, rpc

Let's suppose I have 2 server `A` & `B`. server `B` is running some application say `nodejs` and displaying some logs.

Now I want server `A` to get those logs show on the server and keep the logs updated if the user is on the same screen. Is it possible?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: System is a broad word, what did you mean by a system?

Comment: you can say ubuntu machine

Comment: have you tried elk stack, elastic search, log stash and kibana?

Comment: no, actually I am very new to this. So I do not have any idea what should I use

Answer (score 0):

Elatic.co provide a set of tools for remote logging which is also called the ELK stack, You can learn more about the ELK stack here at [logstash official website](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

This is called centralized logging which became very popular lately.